# Dojo domConstruct.create won't create element on postCreate

Tags: dojo, widget, episerver

I'm new to Dojo and I'm making my first widget to be used in EPiServer CMS. 
The widget is supposed to dynamically add contacts when clicking on a button. This means that the only control my templateString has is a button. When clicking on it I call a function that creates all of the other controls that will contain the contact infomation, such as name, email etc. This is working fine, I use domConstruct.create without a problem.

Thing is, when I want to create the existing contacts based on the value that comes from the server I can't manage to use domConstruct.create, it just returns "undefined". I'm making the call in the postCreate event which happens after the DOM is ready. (I've tested this as well). Does anyone have a clue what could be wrong?  Like I said creating the controls when clicking on the Add button works like a charm.

The function that throws the error is:

```
postCreate: function () {
            // call base implementation
            this.inherited(arguments);

            //this._loadContacts(this.value);
            var node = domConstruct.create("fieldset", { id: "test" }, "cccp"); //this simple create instruction returns undefined here. 

            //Bind button
            this.connect(this.btnAdd, "onclick", dojo.partial(this._createContact, new Object()));

        },
```

Exactly on the line that does the domConstruct.create. Below is the entire code for the widget:

```
define([
    "dojo/_base/array",
    "dojo/_base/connect",
    "dojo/_base/declare",
    "dojo/_base/lang",
    "dojo/dom-construct",
    "dojo/on",


    "dijit/_CssStateMixin",
    "dijit/_Widget",
    "dijit/_TemplatedMixin",
    "dijit/_WidgetsInTemplateMixin",

    "epi/epi",
    "epi/shell/widget/_ValueRequiredMixin"
],
function (
    array,
    connect,
    declare,
    lang,
    domConstruct,
    on,

    _CssStateMixin,
    _Widget,
    _TemplatedMixin,
    _WidgetsInTemplateMixin,

    epi,
    _ValueRequiredMixin
) {
    var amountContacts = 0;
    var contactContainerPrefixName = "contactInfo";

    return declare("meridian.editors.StringList", [_Widget, _TemplatedMixin, _WidgetsInTemplateMixin, _CssStateMixin, _ValueRequiredMixin], {

        templateString: "<div class=\"dijitInline\">\
                            <form id=\"cccp\" action=\"\">\
                            </form>\
                            <button id=\"btnAdd\" data-dojo-attach-point=\"btnAdd\" type=\"button\" class=\"\">Add Contact</button><br/> \
                            <span>${helptext}</span>\
                        </div>",

        baseClass: "epiStringList",

        helptext: "Place items on separate lines",

        intermediateChanges: false,

        value: null,

        multiple: true,

        onChange: function (value) { },

        _onChange: function (value) {
            this.onChange(value);
        },

        postCreate: function () {
            // call base implementation
            this.inherited(arguments);

            //this._loadContacts(this.value);
            var node = domConstruct.create("fieldset", { id: "test" }, "cccp"); //this simple create instruction returns undefined here. 

            //Bind button
            this.connect(this.btnAdd, "onclick", dojo.partial(this._createContact, new Object()));

        },

        isValid: function () {
            // summary:
            //    Check if widget's value is valid.
            // tags:
            //    protected, override

            return !this.required || lang.isArray(this.value) && this.value.length > 0 && this.value.join() != "";
        },


        _loadContacts:function(data)
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                this._createContact(data[i]);
            }
        },


        _createContact:function(data)
        {
            //increase the number of contacts
            amountContacts++;
            var contactInfoContainer = contactContainerPrefixName+amountContacts;

            //Create container for contact data
            var contactInfo = domConstruct.create("fieldset", { id: contactInfoContainer }, "cccp");

            //Create container for PROPERTIES
            var contactInfoProperties = domConstruct.create("div",  {class: "properties"}, contactInfoContainer);

            //Name
            this._createTextbox("name", data.fullName, "Name", contactInfoProperties, false, false);

            /*//Email
            this._createTextbox("email", "Email", contactInfoProperties, false);

            //Phone 1
            this._createTextbox("phoneOne", "Phone 1", contactInfoProperties, true);

            //Phone 2
            this._createTextbox("phoneTwo", "Phone 2", contactInfoProperties, true);

            //Fax
            this._createTextbox("fax", "Fax", contactInfoProperties, false);

            //Organization
            this._createTextbox("organization", "Organization", contactInfoProperties, false);

            //Department
            this._createTextbox("department", "Department/Unit", contactInfoProperties, false);

            //Role
            this._createTextbox("role", "Role/Job title", contactInfoProperties, false);*/

            //Website
            this._createTextbox("website", data.website, "Website", contactInfoProperties, false, false);

            //Address
            //this._createTextbox("address", "Address", contactInfoProperties, false);

            //TLP
            this._createTLP_DDL("tlp", "TLP", contactInfoProperties);


            //Create container for CATEGORIES
            var contactInfoCategories = domConstruct.create("div", { class: "categories" }, contactInfoContainer);

            //Categories heading
            var p=domConstruct.create("p", { class: "heading" }, contactInfoCategories);
            p.innerHTML = "Categories";

            //Alert, Warning & Incident Response
            this._createCategory("alert", contactInfoCategories, "Alert, Warning & Incident Response");

            //Threat
            this._createCategory("threat", contactInfoCategories, "Threat");

            //Vulnerability
            this._createCategory("vulnerability", contactInfoCategories, "Vulnerability");

            //Industry
            this._createCategory("industry", contactInfoCategories, "Industry");

            //Policy
            this._createCategory("policy", contactInfoCategories, "Policy");

            //R & D
            this._createCategory("rd", contactInfoCategories, "R & D");

            //Sharing
            this._createCategory("sharing", contactInfoCategories, "Sharing");

            //Crime
            this._createCategory("crime", contactInfoCategories, "Crime");

            //SCADA/Process Control
            this._createCategory("scada", contactInfoCategories, "SCADA/Process Control");

            //Assurance
            this._createCategory("assurance", contactInfoCategories, "Assurance");

            //Standards
            this._createCategory("standards", contactInfoCategories, "Standards");

            //Resilience
            this._createCategory("resilience", contactInfoCategories, "Resilience");

            //Exercises
            this._createCategory("exercises", contactInfoCategories, "Exercises");

            //Defence
            this._createCategory("defence", contactInfoCategories, "Defence");

            //Media handling
            this._createCategory("media", contactInfoCategories, "Media handling");

            //General PoC
            this._createCategory("poc", contactInfoCategories, "General PoC");



            //Add remove button
            var btnRemove = domConstruct.create("input", { type: "button", id: "btnRemove" + amountContacts, value: "Remove"/*,onclick:"_deleteContact(this)"*/ }, contactInfo);
            this.connect(btnRemove, "onclick", dojo.partial(this._deleteContact, btnRemove.id));

        },

        _createTextbox:function(id, textBoxValue, labelText, parent, checkbox, checkboxChecked)
        {
            var currentId = id+amountContacts;

            var textboxContainer = domConstruct.create("div",  {class:"form-item"}, parent);

            this._createLabel(currentId, textboxContainer, labelText);

            //Create textbox and attach update handler
            var textbox = domConstruct.create("input", { type: "text", id: currentId, name: currentId }, textboxContainer);
            if (textBoxValue)
                textbox.value = textBoxValue;

            this.connect(textbox, "onchange", this._updateValue);

            if (checkbox) {
                this._createCheckbox("inline", textboxContainer, currentId + "_24", "24/7?");
            }
        },


        _createTLP_DDL:function(id, labelText, parent)
        {
            var currentId = id+amountContacts;

            var ddlContainer = domConstruct.create("div", { class: "form-item" }, parent);
            this._createLabel(currentId, ddlContainer, labelText);

            var ddl = domConstruct.create("select", { name: currentId, id: currentId }, ddlContainer);

            //Add options
            var option1 = domConstruct.create("option", { val: "-1" }, ddl);
            option1.innerHTML = "None";

            var option1 = domConstruct.create("option", { val: "1" }, ddl);
            option1.innerHTML = "Yes";

            var option1 = domConstruct.create("option", { val: "0" }, ddl);
            option1.innerHTML = "No";
        },

        _createCategory:function(id, parent, checkboxText)
        {
            var currentId = id + amountContacts;


            var categoryContainer = domConstruct.create("div", { class: "form-item inline" }, parent);
            this._createCheckbox("", categoryContainer, currentId, checkboxText);
        },

        _createLabel:function(forId, container, labelText)
        {
            var label = domConstruct.create("label", { for: forId }, container);
            label.innerHTML = labelText;
        },

        _createCheckbox:function(labelClass, container, checkboxId, checkboxText){
            var labelCheckbox = domConstruct.create("label", { class: labelClass }, container);

            //Create checkbox and attach update handler
            var checkbox = domConstruct.create("input", { type: "checkbox", id: checkboxId, name: checkboxId }, labelCheckbox);
            this.connect(checkbox, "onchange", this._updateValue);

            var span = domConstruct.create("span", {}, labelCheckbox);
            span.innerHTML = checkboxText;
        },

        _deleteContact:function(targetBtnId)
        {
            var userInput = window.confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this contact?");
            if (userInput) {
                dojo.destroy(contactContainerPrefixName+targetBtnId[targetBtnId.length-1]);
            }
        },

        _updateValue: function () {
            //TODO: Delete test data
            var contacts = [];

            //The amount of contacts can have changed after deletions, so the global variables might not hold the real value
            var actualAmountContacts = 0;

            for (var i = 1; i <= amountContacts; i++) {
                if (this._isValidContact(i)) {

                    var currentContact = new Object();
                    currentContact.fullName = this._getValueById("name" + i);
                    currentContact.website = this._getValueById("website" + i);

                    contacts[actualAmountContacts] = currentContact;
                    actualAmountContacts++;
                }
            }



            this._set("value", contacts);
            this.onChange(contacts);
        },

        _getValueById: function (id) {
            var node = dojo.byId(id);
            var textValue = (node != null) ? node.value : "";
            return textValue;

        },

        _isValidContact:function(itemNumber){
            //If there's no name or telephone then it's not a valid contact
            return (this._getValueById("name" + itemNumber) != "" || this._getValueById("phoneOne" + itemNumber) != "" || this._getValueById("phoneTwo" + itemNumber) != "");
        },
    });
});
```

UPDATE:
After a lot of test I've realized it's not the domConstruct.create statement which causes the error, the problem is that the form element that has "id:cccp" and to which I want to attach the created elements is null at this point. It is defined in the templateString as you can see in the source code but it's still null in the postCreate method. So the question is now, what event gets triggered when the HTML in the templateString is loaded?

Comment: this is too much code to read. can you give us the snippet where you are getting the error. When you make a server request you are most likely using a asynchronous call. For handling Async calls you either need to use a promise or pass a callback function for doing something with the data. You cannot use a normal assignment function call to get data.

Comment: I have edited the question and added the snippet that causes the error. Sometimes you need more code to actually see the context. Anyways, I'm not doing any server request by hand, it's the CMS that does it for me. At the point where the "postCreate" method is called the object "this.value" has already the correct data that was saved on the server. The line where this data is used is commented for simplicity now. The error still occurs when I create a random element with hard coded data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I solved the problem, so I write the workaround here and I hope it helps somebody! 
I changed the templateString and added the attribute `data-dojo-attach-point=\"form\"` to the form that was not being found. Then in the postCreate method I accessed the form using this (`this.form` ), which worked without a problem. The final implementation for the function turned out as follows:

```
postCreate: function () {
            // call base implementation
            this.inherited(arguments);

            //this._loadContacts(this.value);
            var node = domConstruct.create("fieldset", { id: "test" }, this.form); //this simple create instruction returns undefined here. 

            //Bind button
            this.connect(this.btnAdd, "onclick", dojo.partial(this._createContact, new Object()));

        },
```

I still don't understand why `dojo.byId("cccp")` would return null, but I'm happy I found a workaround that solved the problem. Cheers!